# install centos older kernel version

Tags: centos, kernel, yum, repository

Currently I'm using Kernel version `3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64`
and I want to downgrade to `3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64` (that was not installed, it needed to support existing project)

I've tried:

```
yum install  kernel-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.gigenet.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfastnet.com
 * extras: mirror.steadfastnet.com
 * updates: mirror.steadfastnet.com
No package kernel-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Did you download and install CentOS 7.7 with 3.10.0-1062.el7? If you did, then you're not going to be able to download and you'll just have to install CentOS 7.6. Running an older version of a kernel leaves you open to security vulnerabilities and compromises your system. If there is software that won't work with the current kernel, then it's better to reach out to the developers.

Comment: Security is not in issue, because this server have no connection to the world. and to support the latest will make too much work, because it depend on third parties

Comment: If it has no connection to the world, then how do you plan on using yum? There's also the fact that running an older kernel and older system libraries will cause other issues.

Comment: after i finish i disable the interface, (in previews  workplace we had a local copy of the entire repo)

Comment: Then you're going to need to enable it which opens you and your entire organization up to attack. That's going to be the case whenever you need anything from the internet. Aside from security, there's functionality from latee resources where you'll need to enable a network connection to the outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... want to downgrade to 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64

`kernel-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64` was saved / is stored at CERN :

https://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64.rpm

Ref. https://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/centos/7/updates/x86_64/repoview/kernel.html ... and ref. Google https://www.google.com/search?q=kernel-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64

Download ... and install :

```
# yum install Downloads/kernel-3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: ill give it a try